# How to get D1 D7 D30 without left join on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, outer-join

**Objective:**

I would like to know everyone who signed up on Day 0, how many of them logged in after D1, after D7 and after D30. I would like to make a table valued function where the users inserts a date and gets results for D0, D1, D7, D30.
Results should look like this:

```
Date        TotalD0 TotalD1 TotalD7 TotalD30
2019-04-01    3         3      2       1
```

**Situation:**

I have one login table with email and login_time. I left joined three times on the same table and it worked on a dummy table. However, when using real data with millions of rows, it ran forever. There has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

**What i tried:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnTestData
(
    @StartDate AS Date
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    select @startdate, 
       COUNT(distinct t1.id) As TotalD0, 
       COUNT(distinct t1a.id) As TotalD1,
       COUNT(distinct t1b.id) As TotalD7,
       COUNT(distinct t1c.id) As TotalD30
    from #test1 t1
       left join #test1 t1a on t1.id=t1a.id and t1a.login_time >= 
             DATEADD(day,1,t1.login_time)
       left join #test1 t1b on t1.id=t1b.id and t1b.login_time >= 
             DATEADD(day,7,t1.login_time)
       left join #test1 t1c on t1.id=t1c.id and t1c.login_time >= 
             DATEADD(day,30,t1.login_time)
    where t1.login_time = @startdate
    group by t1.login_time
```

**Test data:**

```
create table #test1 (id int, login_time date)
insert into #test1 values
(1, '2019-04-01'),
(1, '2019-04-01'),
(1, '2019-04-02'),
(1, '2019-04-19'),
(1, '2019-05-05'),
(2, '2019-04-01'),
(2, '2019-04-05'),
(2, '2019-04-10'),
(2, '2019-04-15'),
(3, '2019-04-01'),
(3, '2019-04-01'),
(3, '2019-04-02')
```

Comment: @SalmanA StartDate (the user's input)

Comment: For your test data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Your table has login time, but your question is about signing up.  I'm confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff typo (its login time)

Comment: @WillardSolutions it should look exactly like the expected result in my question

Comment: The date of `2019-04-10` in your question is well after most of  the dates in your sample data.  I don't understand your math

Comment: The query seems to suggest that a person *must have logged in* on start_date and possibly later. Is that correct?

Comment: its not related to the test data below. ill modify it now.

Comment: @SalmanA That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could be translated to a `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '2019-04-01'

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) D0
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN login_time >= DATEADD(DAY,  1, @StartDate) THEN id END) AS D1
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN login_time >= DATEADD(DAY,  7, @StartDate) THEN id END) AS D7
     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN login_time >= DATEADD(DAY, 30, @StartDate) THEN id END) AS D30
FROM #test1 AS t
WHERE login_time >= @StartDate
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM #test1 AS x
    WHERE x.id = t.id
    AND x.login_time = @StartDate
)
```

```
D0    D1    D7    D30
3     3     2     1
```

You need to create appropriate indexes to speed it up.

Comment: i only need to know if the person logged in at least once after D1, D7, D30

Comment: Ah... so if a person logged in between d1 and d7 and after d30 he is counted once? between d1 and d7?

Comment: If a person logs 20 times after D1, he is counted once for the D1 column. If he loggs in 14 times after D7 then once again but for D7 Column.

Comment: What is the EXISTS part  doing at the end? the result still work without it

Comment: @roger I translated your query as-is ignoring all comments. Your query seems to find next logins for people who logged in on the start_date... this part ensures just that. It'll not count a person who logged in on April-2 but did not login on April-1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do cohort analysis based on the day people start:

```
select first_ld,
       count(*) as num_d0,
       sum(case when login_date >= dateadd(day, 1, firstld) then 1 else 0 end) as num_d1,
       sum(case when login_date >= dateadd(day, 7, firstld) then 1 else 0 end) as num_d7,
       sum(case when login_date >= dateadd(day, 30, firstld) then 1 else 0 end) as num_d30
from (select id, convert(date, login_time) as login_date,
             min(convert(date, login_time)) over (partition by id) as first_ld
      from #test1 t
      group by id, convert(date, login_time)
     ) t
group by first_ld
order by first_ld;
```

Comment: this seems to add all of them. It should only count distinct number of people. I should get 3, 3, 2, 1 respectively .

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it seems the OP isn't being very clear about what he is really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RogerSteinberg . . . It should be generating a decreasing sequence.  And it should work for every day when someone starts.